# how to count number of item in XMl item (Node List)

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML
int displayPerPage = 5; 
int TotalRows = xml.length();
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
// looping through all item nodes <item>

for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
   // creating new HashMap
     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    menuItems.add(map);
}
```

This is my Code i want to Count nUmber of node i m not able to do this please tell me how i will do it http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml suppose this my xml contaion 10 item or Node how i will count please post me code for that

Comment: getLength returns the number of nodes in the list. The range of valid child node indices is 0 to length-1 inclusive. And it is available in android since api level 1

Comment: check doc value,sure it not null.because nl.getLength() give value 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `nl.getLength()`, it'll return you the number of items in each  tag.

Comment: getLength() is not there in constructor when i sue this

Comment: getLength() is not in constructor when i *USE

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    System.out.println("Total of elements : " + list.getLength());
```

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-count-xml-elements-in-java-dom-parser/).